# How can I use globalCompositeOperation to merge/overlay two images?

Tags: javascript

How can I use `globalCompositeOperation` to combine two images into one? I am not sure which one is best but I would like to experiment with `source-over` or `source-in`

Consider this MWE (but not quite!):

```
<html>

<div id="t-bg"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 55px top; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;);">
</div>
<br> <br> <br> <br> <br>

clickme
<div id="t-fg"

    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left top; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;);">
</div>

</html>

<script>
function b64toImageData(datas) {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        // We create an image to receive the Data URI
        var img = document.createElement("img");

        // When the event "onload" is triggered we can resize the image.
        img.onload = function () {
            // We create a canvas and get its context.
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            // We set the dimensions at the wanted size.
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            // We resize the image with the canvas method drawImage();
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            // get image data
            var imageDatas = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

            // This is the return of the Promise
            resolve(imageDatas);
        };
        // add data to img
        img.src = datas;
    });
}


function imagedata_to_image(imagedata) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = imagedata.width;
    canvas.height = imagedata.height;
    ctx.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0);

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    return image;
}


function MergeImg(bg, fg) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var bg = imagedata_to_image(bg);
    var fg = imagedata_to_image(fg);

    ctx.drawImage(fg, 0, 0, 300, 80); 
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 55, 0, 300, 80);
    var imageDatas = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 80);
    var newImage = imagedata_to_image(imageDatas);
    console.log('newimg', newImage);
    return newImage;
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    let el = e.target;
    if (el.id == "t-fg") {

        // get base64
        var fg = document.getElementById("t-fg").style.backgroundImage.slice(5, -2);
        var bg = document.getElementById('t-bg').style.backgroundImage.slice(5, -2);

        // get ImageData
        var bg_img = await b64toImageData(bg);
        var fg_img = await b64toImageData(fg);

        // merge
        var out = MergeImg(bg_img, fg_img);


    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `source-over` is the default, setting it explicitly to that won't change anything. It's hard to say because "overlay" could mean a lot of things in this context. Also whenever you change one of the global properties of a ctx in a function I always like to save the old value in a temp var and set it back to the way it was before the function returns, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: I would like a single image, ultimately, where `t-bg` is visible in the gaps in `t-fg`